# What is the card type Phenomenon and Ongoing?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Default.aspx) has the Card Type "Phenomenon" and "Ongoing". Does anyone knows what those two refer to?

Comment: A quick Google search for "mtg ongoing" and "mtg phenomenon" gives an easy answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are used in *Magic* variant formats; that is, not the "usual" rules of the game.

- **Phenomenon** is a card type used in the [Planechase](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/2012-edition-frequently-asked-questions-2012-05-24) format. Cards of this type are oversized, and put in a separate *planar deck*, along with **Plane** cards, not the deck that becomes the player's library.
- **Ongoing** is a supertype that only applies to the **Scheme** card type, which is used in the [Archenemy](https://web.archive.org/web/20160117184705/http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/91) variant. Cards of this type are also oversized, and put in a separate *scheme deck*.